# found button but unable to click on it

Tags: python, selenium

I have a methods which fills facebook sign up for and should to press "Create an account" button. It seams that it founds button, but due to unclear reason unable to click on it

code of button is:

```
<button type="submit" class="_6j mvm _6wk _6wl _58mi _3ma _6o _6v" name="websubmit" id="u_0_s">Create Account</button>
```

and my method is:

```
def submit_new_account_form(self, **credentials):

    firstname = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(self.__first_name_field_css)
    lastname = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(self.__last_name_field_css)
    number_or_email = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(self.__mobile_number_or_email_field_css)
    newpass = self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.__new_password_field_id)
    maleradio = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(self.__male_radio_css)
    femaleradio = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(self.__female_radio_css)
    submit_button = self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.__create_account_button_id)


    if submit_button:
        print ("submit button found")

    if maleradio:
        print("maleradio found")
    if femaleradio:
        print ("femaleradio found")
    #firstname.clear()
    if credentials['first_name']:
        firstname.send_keys(credentials['first_name'])

    #lastname.clear()
    if credentials['last_name']:
        lastname.send_keys(credentials['last_name'])

    #number_or_email.clear()
    if credentials['phone_or_email']:
        number_or_email.send_keys(credentials['phone_or_email'])
        re_enter_email_field = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,self.__re_enter_new_email_field_css)))
        re_enter_email = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(self.__re_enter_new_email_field_css).send_keys(
            credentials['phone_or_email'])

    #newpass.clear()
    if credentials['newpass']:
        newpass.send_keys(credentials['newpass'])

    if credentials['sex'] == 'male':
        maleradio.click()

    if credentials['sex'] == 'female':
        femaleradio.click()

    submit_button.click()


    if submit_button.click():
        print('submit button clicked')
```

each time I run script submit button clicked doesn't appears and error occurs:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

Comment: the button is not visible when you trying to click it. you need to wait until it actually shows up otherwise selenium will raise. Are you sure the button is always visible on the page? or does it appear once you fill in the form?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" class="_6j mvm _6wk _6wl _58mi _3ma _6o _6v"
name="websubmit" id="u_0_s">Create Account</button>
```

From above,I could see **id for submit button is** '**id='u_0_s**'.
Can you confirm that you are passing id correctly for submit?
If not,please correct it with 'id='**u_0_s**',try and let me know if it works.

Also,check if the Submit button is visible while your test case is getting executed.You can add code to maximize browser window for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath: `"//button[contains(text(), 'Create an account')]"`, it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I have added implicit wait

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, self.__create_account_button_id)))
```

And after that everything works good